# How can I update my App in the App Store if the Distribution Provisioning Profile expired?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want to update an existing App in the App Store, but the profile I used expired (I'm not sure, if it has something to do with the corresponding certificate which also expired..). Since Apple tells me in the How-Tos:

*Use the same Distribution Provisioning
 Profile to build each new version of
 your application*

I don't know, what to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The important part is keep the same bundle id.

If your provisioning profile has expired or you has to generate another certificate, it doesn't matter.

Get anew version of you provisioning profile, build your app and it should be fine.

Comment: what if i have push notifications enabled for the app, do i have to create the certificate again?

Comment: The certificate used to build the app is different from the cert used for the push. You only need to generate a new APS certificate if it has expired. You can see that the APS certificate is bounded to the App Id, and not to the distribution certificate.

Answer (score 3):

If the profile is expired, simple renew it or generate a new one. I did it yesterday, my dist profile was expired and I simply deleted it and generated a new one.

Once a new one certificate is generated, download it, delete the old one from your keychain and add the new one.

After that, try to build your app. (Sometimes restarting Xcode is required)

Answer (score 2):

Every profile and every certificate will expire. As long as the developer account is still the same, simply creating a new distribution cert should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep exactly two things the same: the enrolled iOS Developer account you use, and the Target Identifier Property in Xcode (becomes the Bundle Identifier in the app).  Do that, and the result will be an update to the same app in the App store.

Everything else you can renew, recreate in the portal, install on a new Mac, etc., including App IDs (wildcard on not) created in the portal, Developer or Distribution certificates, and provisioning profiles in the portal, installed in Xcode or on the iDevice.  You can also change the Bundle display name (under the icon), the Product name, the Target name in Xcode, and maybe even the name of the app as it appears in the App store (if it's not misleadingly different).

Comment: I have changed the provisioning profile on a couple apps (wildcard to non-wildcard for adding IAP) and they were accepted, so the documentation you quote seems to be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Renew your certificate and provisioning profile at the iOS Developer Portal.

Comment: You can't really "renew" your Distribution Provisioning Profile. In my case I had to create a new one from scratch.

Comment: Providing you kept the original CSR, you can renew a distribution certificate and it's related provisioning profile.