# After renewing my iOS membership, is it necessary to update my apps with new distribution profiles signed with a new distribution certificate?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Background: I have some existing apps in the App Store and I have just renewed my Apple Developer Program membership.

Appreciate if someone can help with these questions:

1. Is it necessary to release an update for each of my apps, compiled with a new distribution profile and signed with a new distribution certificate?
2. If I don't do the above (1), will my apps expire and disappear from the App Store?
3. Will a user who has previously downloaded my app, but have yet to install the update, be able to use my app even after its distribution profile has expired?

I found a related question, but it doesn't specifically address the above questions:
[How can I update my App in the App Store if the Distribution Provisioning Profile expired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751362/how-can-i-update-my-app-in-the-app-store-if-the-distribution-provisioning-profi)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.** No, your apps are there to stay on the app store. Distribution profiles do not expire until you force them to. Even then, the expiration only keeps you from submitting new apps with that certificate. It does not effect pre-existing applications.

**2.** Nope! Jeez, that'd suck...

**3.** Yes. Apple actually applies their own certificate to your app once it is submitted. Your distribution certificate only goes as far as Apple's verification process.

You're good friend. No need to freak out. The provisioning/signing/profile process is a pain in the a**, but fortunately for us we don't have to worry about things like this.

Comment: All my apps on app store were suspended because the account had expired and hence were not showing on app store, but after renewing my account my apps are not showing on app store now. Does it take some time to show after account renewal or is there something else to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have renewed it then there is no need to Do all these stuffs :)

1) You cannot Update a new Version with Different Certificate... you have to use that only.

2) if you do not Renew your Certificate, i think so they are removed from Sale only. :(
But as Peter Said May be he hi Right :)

You can find a lots of links having Queries like this... Hope you will find and get the solutions. :)

All the Best :)

Comment: I'm a little confused here. With reference to your 1) - suppose I have important updates to my app after the expiry of my old distribution certificate, what should I do?

Comment: You should Renew your certificate then... I am sorry if i have confused you.  If you want to update your app on app store You have to use the same Provisioning Profile which you have used while Submitting the previous versions :)